# JQgrid Sorting date on the client side with a specific format

Tags: date, jqgrid, customization

I am using JQGrid to store the data which is being loaded on the client side itself.
I want sort the date which is in a customized format(i.e. 11-Nov-2010). I want to sort it on the client side (due to the requirement). Can anyone of you suggest me what I need to do?

Thanks in Advance!

With Regards

Phani Kumar

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jqGrid support [date formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types). It allows to display the date in the grid in the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) which you prefer. You need only the choose the corresponding formatter option like

```
sorttype:'date', formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'d-M-Y'}
```

So you can fill the grid in one format (default format form is ISO Date format Y-m-d and I recommend you to use this format). You can also use `Date` type as input for the local data. The option `newformat` define the format of data which *will be displayed* for the user. Internally the date will be hold and sorted as the `Date` JavaScript type.

To make easy to use practically what I explained above I created small [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortedData1.htm) example which you can see live and examin it's JavaScript code.