# jqGrid Date Filtering and Sorting

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that presents client side data.  One of the fields in the array is a Date field, and it's representation in the client side array is a "LONG" value.  I created a customer cell formatter to turn that into a mm/dd/yyyy string.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the "searching" and "filtering toolbar" to understand how to search/filter.

I searched around for other answers to this question, to no avail.  I did try the "sorttype" function such as:

```
            stype: 'text',
            sorttype: function (cell) {
                var date = new Date (cell);
                return date.getMonth().toString() + '/' + date.getDate().toString() + '/' +  date.getFullYear().toString();
            }
```

but that did not work either.  If anyone has any tips or points, I would greatly appreciate the help.  Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The exact definition for the column is:

```
  ,{
    name: "Original_Delivery_Date",
    align: 'center',
    formatter: cellDateFormatter,
    editable: true,
    sorttype: 'int'
  }
```

Here is the formatter I use:

```
  /**
   * Converts from a LONG date (1318636800000) to YYYY-MM-DD format.
   */
  function cellDateFormatter (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    if (cellValue == null || cellValue == '') {
        return '';
    }
    var dt = new Date (cellValue);
    return (dt.getUTCMonth () + 1) + '/' + dt.getUTCDate () + '/' + dt.getUTCFullYear ();
  }
```

Comment: Could you include exact definition of the column in `colModel` which has the Date field? Which exactly data you use as input for the column?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544381/jqgrid-sorting-date-on-the-client-side-with-a-specific-format

Comment: I should also add that it's not the sorting that's the main problem.  The sorting actually works because the field is a "LONG" value (so I guess my title was not 100% accurate, my apologies).  It's the filtering that's causing the problem (the filter/search toolbar, that is).  It is attempting to filter by the "LONG" value, and not the actual date (ex: 3/3/2013).

Comment: This code was written some time ago, which is probably why it uses a custom formatter as opposed to just using the built in functionality.  I changed the code to use the suggestion from Tutan Ramen, and it still fails to be able to filter by the date because the filter is using the backing data as the item to filter on (in this case, the "LONG" value).

Comment: I guess the question should have been phrased as, "How can I get the filter toolbar to filter on the date column's NEW format?"