# JQgrid sort by date that is sent as string by server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My server is sending a date to javascript as **string** in format of

> "csd":"08-SEP-2015"

I want to sort the data by date on this column. But the sorting doesnt works.

here is my colModel

```
{
                name: 'csd',
                index: 'csd',
                width: 110,
                align: 'left',
                sorttype: 'date',
                datefmt:'d-M-Y'
   }
```

**Update1:**

I am using  jqGrid 4.5.4 - jQuery Grid

**Added note:** I dont want to format the date, i just want the column to be sortable as date.

**Update2:**

I updated the definition as

```
{
                name: 'csd',
                index: 'csd',
                width: 110,
                align: 'left',
                sorttype: 'date',

                formatter:'date',
                formatoptions:{srcformat:'d-M-Y' , newformat:'d-M-Y'}
            }
```

but now I am getting `NaN-undefined` in the field.

Marking the question for close,Answer found at:

[JQgrid Sorting date on the client side with a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544381/jqgrid-sorting-date-on-the-client-side-with-a-specific-format)

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: @oleg I will check and update the question tomorrow...

Comment: In general I can say directly, that I recommend you to use `formatter: "date"` with `formatoptions` where you specify `srcformat` and `newformat`. You can remove `datefmt` which will be ignored in the case. It should solve your problem, but the results can be a little different depend on which version of jqGrid you use. I recommend you to include always information about the fork of jqGrid which you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or old jqGrid in version <=4.7) and in which version.

Comment: @Oleg  jqGrid  4.5.4 - jQuery Grid, this is what i am using.

Comment: Could you try to replace (at least temporary) URL to jqGrid to URLs to free jqGrid 4.9.2 (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). You use **very bad** format of input data which contains locale specific texts ("SEP"). It was the bug in old versions of jqGrid in parsing of such dates. If the usage of free jqGrid 4.9.2 fixes the problem than jqGrid 4.5.4 still contains the old bug.

Comment: @Oleg I would not agree with the term "BAD" here as it a valid PHP format and  it was a client provided format. I also can not change the jqgrid version on my own as its an enhancement that i am working on.

So i have gone ahead and started using the ISO format date yyyy-mm-dd at the database and just converting the date to required format.

the issue has been solved

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQgrid Sorting date on the client side with a specific format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544381/jqgrid-sorting-date-on-the-client-side-with-a-specific-format)

Comment: Bad is any communication with the server which contains **locale specific format**. The only standard for the date is [ISO 8601](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: 2015-09-25 in the simplest case. The formats like 25/9/2015, 9/25/2015, 08-SEP-2015 depends from **locale** which are used. In the same way one can have problem with time zone or daylight saving time (summertime, wintertime). ISO format is specially designed to solve such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad to use language specific format for transferring the data. The format `d-M-Y` is locale dependent. I'm not PHP developer, but see that PHP have setlocale() and Date/Time Functions should depend on the locale. In the same way the format `d-M-Y` used by `formatter: "date"` is also locale dependent and you will have different results depend on the locale which you use (try `grid.locale-de.js`, `grid.locale-ru.js`, `grid.locale-jp.js` ans so on).

I would recommend you to use [ISO 8601](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: which will display 08-SEP-2015 as 2015-09-08 in the simplest case.